# Regex Match Return all Numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this data in a Google Sheets Column

```
A2: BOX OF BOTTLES 
A3: BOX OF 10 BOTTLES 
A4: BOX OF 20 BOTTLES 
A5: BOX OF 30 BOTTLES
```

I would like my formula REGEXMATCH to return in this format :

```
B2 : BX-BT
B3 : BX-10BT
B4 : BX-20BT
B5 : BX-30BT
```

Thats my first try :

=IFS(REGEXMATCH(A2,"BOX OF BOTTLES"),"BX-BT". So its not working now if i have numbers like in A3,A4 and A5

Is there a way to make it work in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `REGEXREPLACE` we can try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "BOX OF (?:(\d+) )?BOTTLES", "BX-$1BT")
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

From your comments below, it seems that the above might not be working for you.  This could be, going by your question, because you have trailing whitespace in your input text.  Try accounting for that in the regex pattern:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "BOX OF (?:(\d+) )?BOTTLES\s*", "BX-$1BT")
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegelesion, Thanks for your help i tried your formula https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jL8HY4akatTccSPCBHmu7uVIMvlAZnOvXYBQ4QiUe-0/edit?usp=sharing M

Comment: ...and...what happened?  The logic is working in the demo at least

Comment: @SimonGIS Please try: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "BOX OF\s*(\d+)?\s*BOTTLES", "BX-$1BT")`

Comment: Aha...it seems you might have some trailing whitespace in your bottle text.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216479/discussion-between-simon-gis-and-tim-biegeleisen).